# How to determine how often a planet's center will be collinear with its moon's?

Tags: natural-satellites, time, mathematics, moon-phases, orbital-resonance

Expanding on the question: Let's say I have a planet orbiting some star (earth-like, sun-like, for the sake of example). If this planet has two moons, M1 with orbital period of 30 earth-days and M2 with orbital period of 50 earth-days, how often will the center of these moons be collinear with the planet's center? What about if there were a third moon, with 70 earth-days orbit?

I tried solving for the intersection between the line formed by the two moons and the planet, but failed in simplifying the resulting equation.

Comment: Can we assume that the moon orbits are perfectly circular and coplanar?

Comment: The key term for this kind of problem is "synodic period". See, eg https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18380/16685 For your problem, you need half the synodic period, because the moons are collinear with the planet when their angular separation is 0° or 180°.